# How to track input checkbox check status

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I got a list of li's and they are sortable with jquery ui, and im trying to make the list sortable or disabled for sorting

if input is checked = enable sorting,
if input is unchecked = disable sorting

this is what i have so far:

```
<ul id="sortable" style="list-style:none">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>

<br />

<label>Sort <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsChecked"/></label
```

JS:

```
function viewModel(){
  self = this;
  self.button = ko.observable();
  self.IsChecked = ko.observable();

  self.enableDrag = function(){
      $("#sortable").sortable();
    console.log("checked");
  }
  self.disableDrag = function(){
    $("#sortable").sortable();
    $("#sortable").sortable("disable");
  }
  self.sort = function(){
    if(self.IsChecked()){
      self.enableDrag();
    }else{
      self.disableDrag();
    }
  }
  self.sort();
};

var myViewModel  = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @kalsowerus sorting is enabled, no matter if the checkbox is checked or unchecked

Comment: Are you sure `myViewModel.sort()` is called when it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the checkbox is going to change the .IsChecked property, but that's it. You can 'subscribe' an event handler to an observable so you can run code when its value changes:

```
self.IsChecked.subscribe(function (newBool) {
   console.log(newBool);
   self.sort();
});
```

This will *only* fire when the value changes. In the case of a checkbox it will be every time the element is clicked because it is a boolean.

See *Explicitly subscribing to observables* in the documentation for more details: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

You can also do this with custom bindings for re-usability:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Comment: Thanks for the help